# Can you have an array of different kinds of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, abstract

I know that you can only have an array of a certain type (e.g. String, int, Student, etc.). I was wondering if this held true in the case of inheritance - i.e. whether or not a Bicycle object that extends Vehicle could be placed in a Vehicle array along with something else, like a Bus object.

Here's my code:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bus bus1 = new Bus();
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        bike1.changeGear(true);
        Bus bus2 = new Bus();
        Vehicle[] myFleet = {bus1, bike1, bus2}; // Note that Vehicle is an abstract class
        for (Bus v: myFleet){ // Trying to access every bus in the Vehicle array. I already
            v.issueTicket(1.50); // tried to get the computer to treat myFleet as a Bus array - doesn't 
            System.out.println(v); // work, sadly.
        }
    }

}
```

*Note that this is in the Java language*

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean?

Comment: Meaning a ClassCastException is thrown. Says that it cannot cast from Vehicle to Bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an array of a super type.

`for` iterates through ALL items in an iterable object (here array).

Since there can be `Bicycle` or `Bus` instances (or even other types, which are currently unknown) in the array, you cannot treat it as a `Bus` Array.

What you probably want is this :

```
for (Vehicle v : myFleet) {
     if (v instanceof Bus) {
         Bus b = (Bus)v;
         b.doSomeSpecialThingsForABus();
     }

}
```

There is no good other way around this except for the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) maybe.

Answer (score 1):

If ClassTwo extends ClassOne and you make an array of ClassOnes, then you can add objects of ClassTwo to the array, however, you may only access members of ClassOne unless you cast.

Comment: Clarification: "members" in this context means methods, fields, etc.

Comment: Okay, how does one cast? I can't seem to get the syntax to work. What you say makes sense, though.

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time to get your point.

If you want to do something like this, you'll have to cast the `Vehicle` into a `Bus`.
However usually you should have an interface common to all vehicles.

As `issueTicket()` does not apply to bicycles you could probably think about not using the same interface for busses and bicycles at all.

Another idea would be to implement the `issueTicket()` method for bicecles just signalling an error as soon as it's called:

```
Vehicle[] myFleet = {bus1, bike1, bus2}; // Note that Vehicle is an abstract class
for (Vehicle v: myFleet){
    v.issueTicket(1.50);
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

However in my opinion this still feels like a design which could be better.

For me to provide some more suggestions it would be good to know the reason why those objects shall be stored within the same container.

Hope that helps.

Best regards,
Joerg

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`java.lang.Object[] myFleet;`

But that could be *too* generic.

If your objects have a common interface (say `Foo`) then you could use

`Foo[] myFleet;`

Also have a look at some Java containers like `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes...but**

**Yes**, you can have an array of Vehicles, eg Bus1, Bus2 and Bike1.

**...But** that doesn't stop your Bike being a Bike, or turn it into a Bus. An array is a list of references to objects, it doesn't take a new copy of the object and turn it into the type of the array: the objects will still be instances of their original class

The Array can hold **vehicles** regardless of their sub-class, it doesn't change them into Buses, Bikes or Vehicles: the type stays the same.

You can try to cast a bike as a bus, however: if you accept that you'll lose any non-bus attributes. You can also use instanceof to decide if the Vehicle is a Bus already, or a Bike, and do conversion stuff if required

ie

```
for (Vehicle v: myFleet){ // For each vehicle in the fleet
    Bus b = (Bus) v; // Turn the vehicle into a bus
    b.issueTicket(1.50);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that bus and bicycle both either extend the same superclass or implement the same interface they can be placed into an array of the type of either the interface or the superclass.

To access those you can check if they are instances of any of the subclasses

```
for (Vehicle v: myFleet){
    if(v instanceof Bus){
        ((Bus) v).issueTicket(1.50); 
    }
}
```

However using instanceof is not advised and in most cases it is better to find either an interface or superclass that describes the generic functionality required for all objects in the array.